# Specifying ManyToMany fields in Django fixtures

Tags: django, many-to-many, fixtures

The documentation on fixtures says you can specify a natural key using the int value of the primary key. For example:

```
{
"pk": 1,
"model": "store.book",
"fields": {
    "name": "Mostly Harmless",
    "author": 42
}
}
```

However it does not say how to reference a manytomany. I have tried using an array:

```
{
"pk": 1,
"model": "store.book",
"fields": {
    "name": "Mostly Harmless",
    "author": [42,43,44]
}
}
```

The way I've written the script to generate the fixture, sometimes there is only one primary key in the array:

```
{
"pk": 1,
"model": "store.book",
"fields": {
    "name": "Mostly Harmless",
    "author": [42]
}
}
```

When running `manage.py loaddata fixture.json` I get the following error:

```
Problem installing fixture 'fixtures/NCT00109798.json': Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 174, in handle
obj.save(using=using)

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 165, in save
models.Model.save_base(self.object, using=using, raw=True)

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 549, in save_base
result = manager._insert(values, return_id=update_pk, using=using)

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 195, in _insert
return insert_query(self.model, values, **kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1518, in    insert_query
return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 788, in execute_sql
cursor = super(SQLInsertCompiler, self).execute_sql(None)

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 732, in execute_sql
cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 15, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 86, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(query, args)

File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 175, in execute
if not self._defer_warnings: self._warning_check()

File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 89, in _warning_check
warn(w[-1], self.Warning, 3)

Warning: Data truncated for column 'keyword' at row 1
```

Is there another way to specify this relationship using fixtures?

Comment: That's the correct way to specify M2M relationship. Have you enclosed all the fixtures in a list? i.e `[ { "pk" : ... }, { "pk" : ... }, ]` .

Comment: I have indeed.  Does the final error message "Warning: Data truncated for column 'keyword' at row 1" mean that I may have an error related to that model?

Comment: It seems to be a MySQL error related to Null fields in your DB. Does the generated fixture have empty entries? http://forums.devshed.com/mysql-help-4/warning-1265-data-truncated-for-column-160831.html

Comment: I replaced empty strings with NULL values. Still getting the same error. I have found that the values being inserted are sometimes larger than what is allowed ( > max_length) value. I will make the changes and see what happens

Comment: That sounds like it could be the problem

Comment: Is there a way to have better error reporting? I have to guess where the validation errors are coming from:  "ValidationError: [u'This value must be an integer.']" It would be very helpful....

Comment: After a few hours of working through bugs, I finally got it to work.  Thanks for all your help @pastylegs. I would like to give you credit for your help, do you want to submit an answer?

Comment: Please, @CMaury post the answer yourself. You have solved the problem, but others are patiently awaiting help. It looks like pastylegs will not be posting a solution.

Comment: Did we ever get an answer to this?